# Node requiring directory rather than specific file

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax

Are these two statements equivalent?

```
const deviceModule = require('..').device;

const deviceModule = require('../device');
```

I thought require needed a module (with our without path) as the parameter. How is it that a directory can be provided and what does the .device do?

Thanks to anyone who can help me understand node.js and javascript better.

Comment: I've edited your question - please don't put code in the titles!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`require('..').device` requires `index.js` from the parent directory, and then gets `device` from that file.

So if you had the following structure:

```
- index.js
- /foo
- - bar.js
```

With `index.js` having the following:

```
module.exports = {
    device: "baz"
};
```

Then `require("..").device` in `bar.js` would give you `"baz"`.

---

[Here is the specification for loading a directory:](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html)

```
LOAD_AS_DIRECTORY(X)
1. If X/package.json is a file,
   a. Parse X/package.json, and look for "main" field.
   b. let M = X + (json main field)
   c. LOAD_AS_FILE(M)
2. If X/index.js is a file, load X/index.js as JavaScript text.  STOP
3. If X/index.json is a file, parse X/index.json to a JavaScript object. STOP
4. If X/index.node is a file, load X/index.node as binary addon.  STOP
```

So in your example, it will:

1. look for `package.json` and get the `main` property, and then load that if it exists
2. If step 1 does not exist, it will load `index.js` if it exists
3. If step 2 does not exist, it will load `index.json` if it exists
4. If step 4 does not exist, it will load `index.node` if it exists

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @ctrax Please don't forget to accept my answer by clicking the tick under the up/down arrows. This lets others know that my answer is the solution, and also gives me some rep as a reward for helping. You get some rep as well for accepting! Everyone wins :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use module require-file-directory.

1- Helps to require all the files only with name. No need to give absolute path of files.
2- Multiple files at a time.